# Compress Image size or Reduce Dimensions of the captured Image

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I compress image size or reduce the dimensions of  the photo which is captured from my windows phone ? 
I use the following lines of code for photo capturing
The captured image size is too large; always more than 2MB and dimensions more 2000 X 2000...........
I want to reduce either of the two.....and save it in my SQlite Database.

```
private async void CaptureBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("AttendanceImage.jpg",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
     await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ImageEncodingProperties` before creating the file.  See if that helps.

```C#
ImageEncodingProperties  my_jpg = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

my_jpg.Width = 640;
my_jpg.Height = 480;

await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(my_jpg, file);
```

---

[MSDN ImageEncodingProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediaproperties.imageencodingproperties.aspx)

Comment: Do you know the code to compress the size of the image ?

Comment: @DenilParmar Depends on what 8.1 you're running.  8.1 runtime or 8.1 Silverlight?  here are some links to help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709935.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediapropertyset.aspx,  and there is a SaveJpeg extension  in Silverlight.